# How to find a maximal odd decomposition of integer M?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Let M be an integer in range [1; 1,000,000,000].

A *decomposition* of M is a set of unique integers whose sum is equal to M.

A decomposition is *odd* if it contains only odd integers.

A decomposition of M is *maximal* if there is no other decomposition of M greater in size of the set.

Write a function:

```
int[] maxOddDecomposition(int M)
```

that returns an array with a *maximal odd decomposition* of M. The numbers in array should be in ascending order. If M does not have any odd decomposition, an array should be empty. If there is more than one correct answer, the function may return any of them.

For example, M = 6 has four decompositions:

```
6 = 1 + 2 + 3
  = 1 + 5
  = 2 + 4
  = 6
```

Only `1 + 5` is an odd decomposition, thus is the maximal odd decomposition. We should return it in array such that `array[0] = 1` and `array[1] = 5`.

Expected worst-case time and space complexity is O(sqrt(M)).

---

What I've tried:

Since the time complexity has to be sqrt(M) it reminded me of naive factorization of M algorithm, where we iterate from 1 to sqrt(M). No further thoughts appeared though. Only that it must be really fast, only sqrt(M) steps.

So, I did some examples. How to find an answer for 20 for example? What are the odd numbers less than 20? 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + ... we already have 16. So, we could add 4, but 4 is even.

So, let's replace 7 with (7 + 4) = 11 and we are done: 1 + 3 + 5 + 11. What I noticed is that the initial sequence had always floor(sqrt(M)) elements, perfect. Let's code it up in pseudo-code:

```
int len = floor(sqrt(M));
int result[] = new int[len];
int sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    result[i] = 1 + 2*i;
    sum += result[i];
}
result[len - 1] = M - sum;
return result;
```

I did a special case for M = 2, returning an empty array. I thought that's it, finito.

I didn't notice that it breaks for 3, because it gives `1 + 2` instead of `3`. And for 5, gives `1 + 3 + 1`, instead of `5`. And for many more.

---

How would you solve it?

Comment: That smells of codechef & co. Not sure SO is the place for such a question.

Comment: Sqrt(n) likely comes from the fact that the 1+3+5+7+.. sum has quadratic growth.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk lol. maybe you should try some sort of back-tracking algorithm e.g. fill it up greedily and go back to remove some elements and replace them with larger numbers

Comment: that thing about floor(sqrt(M)) is so wrong. If M is odd(even) there must be an odd(even) amount of elements in your set. for example say M = 101, floor(sqrt(M)) = 10, but any sum of 10 odd elements will give an even number, every single time

Comment: I have a backtracking solution that seems very fast if you're interested: http://pastebin.com/JqtbGpsR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a deterministic solution to the problem. Suppose M = {1, 3, 5, ..., 2*k-3, 2*k-1, r} where r <= 2*k + 1. It is 'obvious' that the maximal decomposition is not going to have more numbers than (k+1).

We have the following cases for k > 3 (the reasoning and handling of earlier cases is presented later):

Case 1. If r is odd and equal to 2*k+1: add r into the list thereby giving a decomposition of (k+1) elements.

Case 2. If r is even: replace {(2*k-1), r} by {2*k-1+r} giving a decomposition of k elements.

Case 3. If r is odd and not equal to 2*k+1: replace the first and the last two elements in the series {1, 2*k-1, r} by {2*k+r} giving a decomposition of (k-1) elements.

Note that the worst case of (k-1) elements will occur  when the input is of the form n^2 + (odd number < 2*k+1).

Also note that (Case 3) will break in case the number of elements is less than 3. For example, the decomposition of 5 and 7. We will have to special-case these numbers. Likewise (Case 2) will break for 3 and will have to be special-cased. There is no solution for M=2. Hence the restriction k > 3 above. Everything else should work fine.

This takes `O(sqrt(M))` steps.

Some C/C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Enter M:");
    int m = 0;
    scanf("%d", &m);

    int arr[100] = {0};
    printf("The array is:\n");
    switch(m) {
        case 2:
            printf("No solution\n");
            return 0;
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
            printf("%d\n", m);
            return 0;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; (sum + i) < m; i+= 2) {
        arr[count++] = i;
        sum += i;
    }
    int start = 0;
    int r = m - sum;
    if (r % 2 == 0) {
        arr[count - 1] += r;
    } else if (r > arr[count - 1]) {
        arr[count++] = r;
    } else {
        start = 1;
        arr[count - 1] += r + 1;
    }

    for (int i = start; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
Enter M:24
The array is:
1
3
5
15

Enter M:23
The array is:
3
5
15
```

Comment: In case 3, r is odd so surely 2k+r-3 is an even number and not allowed?

Comment: Actually my correction was wrong. Please give me a few minutes.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz , user1952500, please see my answer. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why people have to make it so complicated. An odd decomposition is like a [self-conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Conjugate_and_self-conjugate_partitions) partition turned on its side and unfolded out, for example, `n = 13`

```
4 4 3 2     =>              =>            =>              7 5 1

x x x x   rotate             x         unfold out      x x x x x x x
x x x x   clockwise     ↖  x  x  ↗      each side       x x x x x
x x x     45 degrees      x  x  x           =>               x
x x                      x  x  x  x 
                          x  x  x
```

The larger an odd decomposition is, the larger the "bounding-square" of the corresponding self-conjugate. By "bounding-square" I mean the top left corner square, which is a constant in all similar-sized odd decompositions. For example, we could have written `13` as the self-conjugate `{5,3,3,1,1}` and the 9-cell "bounding square" would remain the same, with corresponding odd decomposition `{9,3,1}`:

```
5 3 3 1 1        =>            9 3 1

x x x x x                x x x x x x x x x
x x x                          x x x
x x x                            x
x
x
```

To get the odd decomposition with the largest cardinality, find the largest "bounding square" with even remainder.

Example:

```
M = 24

Bounding square | remainder
1                 23 
4                 20
9                 15
16                8
25...too large

Place the remainder in any diagonally-symmetric way you like. The simplest way might be

xxxx         xxxxxxxx
xxxx   =>    xxxx
xxxx         xxxx
xxxx         xxxx
             x
             x
             x
             x

Decompose: 15,5,3,1
```

I think this Haskell code outputs all possibilities:

```hs
f m = g [1,3..bestRoot*2 - 1] remainder 0 []
  where root = floor (sqrt (fromIntegral m))
        bestRoot = head $ dropWhile (\x -> odd (m - x^2)) [root,root - 1..1]
        remainder = m - bestRoot^2
        g (x:xs) r prev res
          | null xs   = [reverse ((x + r):res)]
          | otherwise = do r' <- takeWhile (<= div remainder bestRoot) [prev,prev + 2..]
                           g xs (r - r') r' ((x + r'):res)
```

Output:

```
*Main> f 24
[[1,3,5,15],[1,3,7,13],[1,5,7,11],[3,5,7,9]]

*Main> f 23
[[1,3,19],[1,5,17],[1,7,15],[3,5,15],[3,7,13],[5,7,11]]

*Main> f 38
[[1,3,5,7,9,13]]

*Main> f 37
[[1,3,5,7,21],[1,3,5,9,19],[1,3,7,9,17],[1,5,7,9,15],[3,5,7,9,13]]

*Main> f 100
[[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]]
```

Comment: *"I don't see why people have to make it so complicated. An odd decomposition is like a self-conjugate partition turned on its side and unfolded out"* It will be one of my favorite SO quotes :D Could you please add code for your idea?

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk I think I finally got how to output all distributions of the remainder.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea which should work. It requires a net removal of ***at most 1*** number from the greedy set you construct.

Construct your O(sqrt(M)) list as usual (without `result[len - 1] = M - sum;`). If the sum is *not* a square number (i.e. exact):

- Add the *next* largest odd number
- Take the difference between your sum now and your target number -> N

  - If N is odd, remove the corresponding number
  - If N is even *but not 2*, remove the largest odd number smaller than N, and the 1
  - If N is 2, remove the *penultimate* number you just added. This will make the difference 0

Proof:

- If you add the consecutive odd numbers sequentially then the list should be as *dense* as possible - i.e. you cannot have a larger list
- Also the difference is always bounded by the odd number you add in step 2, so a *net* removal of up to two numbers is always accounts of either odd or even differences.

Examples:

- Say you want 42: construct [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], add 13 => sum = 49, remove 7 (no net removal)
- You want 39: construct [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], add 13, remove 1 and 9 (net removal of 1)
- You want 38: construct [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], add 13, remove 11 (no net removals)

EDIT: error in last case corrected courtesy of @user1952500

Comment: For 38, the best answer should be {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13} of size 6. What is mentioned is {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11} + {13} - {11, 1, 3} = {5, 7, 9, 13} which adds up to 34.

Comment: Also, you are removing at most 2 numbers from the greedy list. For example, 39 is greedily constructed as 1+3+5+7+9+11+[3] with the issue with the repeated 3. Then 1, (last 3), 9 are removed and 13 is added. So the net removal is 2 numbers, not 1.

Comment: @user1952500 i see, i missed the last step in his code - i assumed he just filled [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]