# Python recursive algorithm doesn't work for large values - C program works

Tags: python, c, recursion

I wanted to write a backtracking solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277297/how-to-find-a-maximal-odd-decomposition-of-integer-m), which asks to find the most distinct odd numbers that sum up to a given `n`.

I hacked together this Python code:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000) 


stop = False
def solve(n, used, current_sum):
    global stop
    if stop:
        return

    if current_sum == n:
        print(used)
        stop = True
        return

    start = 1 if len(used) == 0 else (used[-1] + 2)
    for i in range(start, n + 1, 2):
        if current_sum + i <= n and not stop:
            used.append(i)
            solve(n, used, current_sum + i)
            used.pop()
        else:
            return

solve(100000000, [], 0)
```

Which, unfortunately, does not print anything for me. As far as I can tell, it never gets to that `if` condition. If I print `current_sum` at each step, it seems to just stop at around `16000000` when the entire program quits with no error.

I tried increasing the recursion limit, no luck.

I tested it on Idle and Eclipse, in Python 3.4, 64 bit, under Windows 8.1. I have 16 GB of RAM.

If I reduce `n`, then I get a solution (remove a zero for example).

This did not make sense to me, so I wanted to see if maybe I have better luck in C. I hacked this in C:

```
int sol[100000];
bool done = false;
void solve(int n, int k, int sum)
{
    if (done)
        return;

    if (sum == n)
    {
        done = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d ", sol[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }

    int start = 1;
    if (k > 0)
        start = sol[k - 1] + 2;
    for (int i = start; i <= n; i += 2)
        if (sum + i <= n && !done)
        {
            sol[k] = i;
            solve(n, k + 1, sum + i);
        }
        else
            return;
}

int main()
{
    solve(100000000, 0, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Which works great even if I add another zero!

What is the deal with Python and how can I get this working for large values as well?

*The execution time for lower values is comparable with the C code, it just quits on me for higher values.*

Comment: So, we have Python and C, but where is C++ affected?

Comment: Isn't the `used` list growing too large? Just after appending to it, please check your assumption: `assert len(used) <= 100000`. If this raises an `AssertionError`, then most probably it was running out of memory because of a large `used`.

Comment: I get a backtrace ending with `File "test.py", line 17, in solve
    for i in range(start, n + 1, 2):
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`.

Comment: Are you sure that you are running it with Python 3.4? `import sys; print(sys.version)`. In Python 2.x, you should use `xrange` instead of `range`, to avoid too much memory use.

Comment: @pts - no assertion error. `100000` is too much even, same behavior even if I assert it under `10000`. I'm sure it's python 3.4 - 3.4.1 actually.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I don't get that. Can you try increasing the recursion limit in the code and see if that changes something please?

Comment: If I add a zero to the recursion limit, it just prints the list.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - even for a billion? Any idea why it would behave differently on my machine? I'm on win 8.1 with 16 gb ram if that helps.

Comment: 32-bit or 64-bit Python? It does work with the same recursion limit for a billion, too. BTW: Do you see any influence from that limit? Does it influence the maximum value you can run your algorithm for?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - 64 bit. Yes, the recursion limit does influence the algorithm for lower values. That's why I added it, because I got recursion depth errors initially. But now there are no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the deal with Python and how can I get this working for large
>   values as well?

I rewrote your code to make it work. You would need to adapt recursion depth when you increase the `n` parameter. I used Python 2.7.6. The idea was to do it the same way as the C code you wrote, the second parameter passed would be an integer and not a list.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) 

sol = []
stop = False

def solve(n, k, current_sum):
    global stop

    if stop:
        return

    if current_sum == n:
    stop = True
    for i in xrange(0, k, 1):
            print(sol[i]),
    print
        return

    start = 1 if len(sol) == 0 else (sol[k-1] + 2)
    for i in xrange(start, n + 1, 2):
        if current_sum + i <= n and not stop:
        sol.append(0)
        sol[k] = i
            solve(n, k + 1, current_sum + i)
        else:
            return

solve(100000000, 0, 0)
```

---

### Discussion of the issue

I tried to read the memory usage of the python code you wrote. I had to set `n = 100.000` in order to get a result of **370 MB**. Adding a `0` made my operating system kill the program. (On Mac OS X I received a memory error).

Here is the code I used on Linux:

```
import os
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)


_proc_status = '/proc/%d/status' % os.getpid()

_scale = {'kB': 1024.0, 'mB': 1024.0*1024.0,
          'KB': 1024.0, 'MB': 1024.0*1024.0}

def _VmB(VmKey):
    '''Private.
    '''
    global _proc_status, _scale
     # get pseudo file  /proc/<pid>/status
    try:
        t = open(_proc_status)
        v = t.read()
        t.close()
    except:
        return 0.0  # non-Linux?
     # get VmKey line e.g. 'VmRSS:  9999  kB\n ...'
    i = v.index(VmKey)
    v = v[i:].split(None, 3)  # whitespace
    if len(v) < 3:
        return 0.0  # invalid format?
     # convert Vm value to bytes
    return float(v[1]) * _scale[v[2]]

def memory(since=0.0):
    '''Return memory usage in bytes.
    '''
    return _VmB('VmSize:') - since


stop = False
def solve(n, used, current_sum):
    global stop

    if stop:
        return

    if current_sum == n:
        print(used)
        stop = True
        return

    start = 1 if len(used) == 0 else (used[-1] + 2)
    for i in range(start, n + 1, 2):
        if current_sum + i <= n and not stop:
            used.append(i)
            solve(n, used, current_sum + i)
            used.pop()
        else:
            return

m0 = memory()
solve(100000, [], 0)
m1 = memory(m0)
print(m1/(1024*1024))
```

In comparison to this result the improved (corrected) code I wrote only uses `4 MB` with the parameter `n` set to `100.000.000`. That's a huge difference indeed.

I am not sure why exactly this is. In particular you have a loop that contains a recursive call (so you call recursively several times from the same branch).

If you insist on using recursive calls, then maybe you'd want to redesign your program. Recursive calls with memorization can be faster than loops in cases. See [this link for example](http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php).

Comment: I know recursion is bad, but this was just something I wrote in a minute to test a hypothesis. How are you getting / seeing the error? I don't see any error message. It should use very little memory, a few megabytes at most (less than a megabyte actually).

Comment: I don't think it uses very little memory. I got disk almost full (using swap space I reckon) because I ran that program. I am sure it is a memory consuming program.

Comment: But it shouldn't be memory consuming. The resulting list has less than `10000` elements. Even if you multiply that by 100 for the stack, the parameters etc., that's still only about 4 MB. Why is it so memory consuming in Python then?

Comment: You mean multiply the number of result elements (10000) by 100 to estimate the number of recursions done?

Comment: More precisely, to estimate the size size of the recursion stack. The number of recursive calls shouldn't matter, only the maximum stack size should matter. Which is bounded by the number of elements in the resulting list, because a single value is added to the list at each call.

Comment: @IVlad I updated my answer. Maybe you can dig deeper based on what I discovered.

Answer (score 1):

I could do some tests with your code use Python3.4 64 bits on Windows 7.

It breaks the same way :

- under IDLE, I get a *RESTART* line saying the Python interpretor had to restart, little before 4000 iterations
- when running directly in a cmd.exe window, I get a system popup saying something like *Python interpretor stopped* (in french *Python.exe a cessé de fonctionner*), littlen after 4000 iterations

I tried it under a FreeBSD 10.1 32 bits virtual machine with as little as 512 Mb of memory, I got a Segmentation fault little after 8000 iterations

I think it is a bug in the CPython interpreter with deep recursion. Because I added some traces and in all my tests it breaked during the initial phase of adding elements to the list before reaching the sum.

I would have accepted any error about abuse of recursion (it is indeed :-) ), but a segmentation fault is really bad : it looks like if Python itself does not control a bound.

---

#### The correct mathematical way

Once we notice that the sum of the n first odd numbers is n<sup>2</sup> (mathematicaly trivial), it is easy to immediately start near the final solution. It would be enough for this example, because 100000000 == 10000<sup>2</sup>. But in the general case, with making last number of `used` list vary, we step the `current_sum` by 2, so we are still missing every second number. But if we go one step previous and start from there, we again step current_sum by 2, but on the other numbers.

So here is a slight variation of original code that works :

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(100000) 


stop = False
def solve(n, used, current_sum):
    global stop
    if stop:
        return

# TRACES
##    print (len(used), used[-1] if len(used) > 0 else '', end=' ')
##    if (len(used) % 10) == 0:
##        print('')

    if current_sum == n:
        print(used)
        global stop
        stop = True
        return

    if current_sum > n: # simple optimisation, no need to go further
        return
    
    # the trick : sum of n first numbers is n*n, and we must start 2 steps before
    if current_sum == 0:
        import math
        l = int(math.sqrt(n)) - 2
        current_sum = l * l
        used = list(range(1, l*2, 2))
        solve(n, used, current_sum)
        return

    start = 1 if len(used) == 0 else (used[-1] + 2)
    for i in range(start, n + 1, 2):
        if current_sum + i <= n and not stop:
            used.append(i)
            solve(n, used, current_sum + i)
            used.pop()
        else:
            return

solve(100000000, [], 0)
```

Comment: Unsure if it is really an answer, but it adds information and is too long for a comment ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Other than making it iterative, do you have any suggestions on how to bypass this bug? I also switched to a while loop that avoids using the `range` object, but the same thing happens. So I think you're right, it looks like some sort of bug when there is a lot of recursion (although 8000 isn't really a lot...)

Comment: @IVlad : Except than doing it non recursive, I cannot imagine a way to bypass the problem :-) . But as the sum of n first odd numbers is `n*n`, you could easily build the initial list with n=sqrt(sum), and only backtrack from there ...

Comment: @IVlad : Here is a slight variation using the fact that  the sum of n first odd numbers is n*n, that works evrywhere ...